# Plotly: Add colorscale in multiple lines plot using Python

Tags: python, time-series, plotly, timeserieschart, plotly-python

#### Summary

I want to add colorscale to multiple lines chart using plotly-python (plotly==3.7.1).

- I don't want to declare each color hex manually.
- The years should order the colormap (ex: 2000 is soft blue ... 2018 is dark blue)

#### Currently plot

[image: series with default colors]

#### Example plot

[image: series with colormap]

#### Code

```
layout = go.Layout(
        title              = '',
        showlegend         = True,
        xaxis = dict(
            title          = '',
            zeroline       = False
        ),
        yaxis = dict(
            title          = '',
            zeroline       = False,
        )
    )    

fig = go.Figure(data = data, layout = layout)
```